# Can you pretty print IHtmlContent?

Tags: asp.net-core

If I have a [`IHtmlContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.html.ihtmlcontent?view=aspnetcore-5.0) can I pretty print it?

Example:

```cs
var html = new HtmlString("<article><h2>Hello!</h2></article>");
```

I want it pretty printed with line breaks and indention into:

```html
<article>
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
</article>
```

I do not want:

```html
<article><h2>Hello!</h2></article>
```

Comment: I think this depends on the actual html it holds. If it's well-formatted, you cay try parsing it into an `XDocument` (built-in) and use `ToString()` to get well-indented html. Otherwise you may have to use a more powerful lib like `htmlagilitypack` to accept even not well-formatted htmls. But then you have to write your own code to convert the loaded nodes into html (the lib does not support rendering to indented html). Finding the other solutions to format indented html from string should give you many results.

Comment: if the original content is not well-formatted, the process of parsing it (into nodes) & formatting back (from the loaded nodes) may remove some text from the original html. So you should be careful about that. Of course if it's ensured to have well format, using `XDocument` may be the best choice and no text will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse it XML with `XDocument.Parse` then use `XmlWriter` with its settings set to `Indent` to true. Worked for me on my HTML too.

```cs
var html = new HtmlString("<article><h2>Hello!</h2></article>");

using var writer = new StringWriter();
html.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
var htmlString = writer.ToString();

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Indent = true,
};

var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
{
    XDocument.Parse(htmlString).Save(writer);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to JavaScript to add the line breaks and indention into, then, use `<pre>` tag to render the html content. Please check the following sample:

Index.cshtml:

```
@{ 
    var html ="<article><h2>Hello!</h2></article>";
}
<div id="printdiv">    
        @Html.Raw(html)
</div>

<div id="output"> 
</div>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printDiv();'>

@section Scripts{
<script>
    function printDiv() {

        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printdiv');
        //display the pretty html content in the web page.
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<pre>" + process(divToPrint.innerHTML).replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") + "</pre>";

        //create a new window to print the div content.
        var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
        newWin.document.open();
        newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()"><pre>' + process(divToPrint.innerHTML).replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") + '</pre></body></html>');
        newWin.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () { newWin.close(); }, 10); 
    }
    function process(str) {

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = str.trim(); 
        return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
    }

    function format(node, level) { 
        var indentBefore = new Array(level++ + 1).join('  '),
            indentAfter = new Array(level - 1).join('  '),
            textNode; 
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) { 
            textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentBefore);
            node.insertBefore(textNode, node.children[i]); 
            format(node.children[i], level); 
            if (node.lastElementChild == node.children[i]) {
                textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentAfter);
                node.appendChild(textNode);
            }
        } 
        return node;
    }
</script>
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I apologize for not being clear enough. I did not want to pretty print it to the end-user in the web browser, I wanted to pretty print it out to a `string` that I could either save to disk or serve to the browser already per-formatted.

Comment: It's okay. It seems that you have already found the solution, congratulation!